# How to delete from a text file, all lines that DO NOT contain a specific string?

Tags: sed

How would I use sed to delete all lines in a text file which do not contain a specific string?

sed '/pattern to match/d' ./infile

I used this command, but it deletes the lines MATCHING a specific pattern,
but what I want is to delete the lines which DO NOT contain a specific pttern?

Comment: Try `sed '/pattern_to_match/!d' file`

Comment: thank yu so much, it worked for me.